# Transitive models of ZFC with satisfaction of formulas without any models(?)

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

So i have started chapter 2 of Jech's Set Theory on Transitive models of ZFC. There are many parts which i don't understand. First let me give some context:

We define restricted quantifiers to be all quantifiers of the form $\forall u \in X$ or  $\exists u \in X$. And next we call a formula $\psi$ a restricted formula if it has no quantifiers other than restricted quantifiers.

Lemma: If $M$ is a transitive class and $\psi$ a restricted formula, then for all $x_1, ... , x_n \in M$, 
$M \models \psi(x_1, ... , x_n)$  iff $\psi(x_1, ... , x_n)$

According to the lemma every transitive model satisfies the axiom of extensionality. Because: $$ [(\forall u \in X)(u \in Y) \wedge (\forall u \in Y)(u \in X)] \rightarrow X=Y$$ is a restricted formula.

My questions: 
1. How is $\psi$ valuated in the lemma at the right side of the equivalence at the absence of a model? Is it valuated under the model that we assume exists for the consistency of ZFC?

2. The axiom of extensionality in the second part is missing the $\forall X \forall Y$ part. Even if we forget about that, since $X$ and $Y$ are free variables of $\psi$ then when we want to check satisfaction we must add the respective quantifiers. So the axiom of extensionality isn't a restricted formula. Am i wrong? Or am i missing something?

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, we assume to work *within* a model of ZFC.
2. For the extensionality, $X$ and $Y$ are considered as free variables, and we can evaluate them as arbitrary elements of $M$.

Comment: About 2. If X and Y are arbitrary then the Axiom of Extensionality isn't a restricted formula. At valution, $\psi$ becomes $Cl(\psi) = \forall X \forall Y \psi$ which isn't restricted.

Comment: Oh, now that they are elements of M it's correct. Thanks!